# JSON ignore fields outside data maps

Tags: json, jackson

I am getting some response :

```
var xxx_api = { "user" : {
   "name":"satishpandey",
   "sites":[
        {
            "name":"SEO Product",
            "url":"http://www.xxx.com/"
        }   ]
}};
```

I want to exclude all the string those are outside json data.

`var xxx_api` and `;` are needs to be excluded.

Is there anything in jackson to exclude these strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any solutions for it in `jackson`. Now I am using `String.substring()` method for getting the desired results.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(jsonString);
stringBuilder.replace(0, stringBuilder.indexOf("{"), "");
stringBuilder.replace(stringBuilder.lastIndexOf("}") + 1, stringBuilder.length(), "");
```

It is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using this in a get/post (restful-like) method, maybe that has to do with the header of the webservice method you are using. I am using REST and I am able to specify the format I want to receive the json input like this

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response myMethod(@FormParam("post") String jsonInput){
    // ...
    // use jsonInput 
    mapper.readValue(jsonInput, ...);
    // ...
}
```

Considering this, I guess the input written to the var `jsonInput` (in the header) would be

```
    { "user" : {
          "name":"satishpandey",
          "sites":[
               {
                   "name":"SEO Product",
                   "url":"http://www.xxx.com/"
               }   ]
    }};
```